# Write sequence (-99K,-98K) in R

Tags: r

I have a below distribution

```
y        p(y)

-99K     0.001
-98K     0.001
-97K     0.001
-96K     0.001
-95K     0.001
5K       0.995
```

I have to retain the same sequence as above, without changing it to `-99000,-98000,-97000,-96000,-95000,5000`.

I need to write the sequence of y in R.

Can anyone help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
R> paste0(rep(-99:-1), "K")
      [1] "-99K"  "-98K"  "-97K"  "-96K"  "-95K"
```

`paste0()` is a variant of `paste()` which just allows you to concatenate a vector with no spaces instead of providing a `sep` parameter.